# Should I tell my dream job I rescinded another offer to wait for their process?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-offer, united-states

I'm a software developer with 4 years experience. I'm in the USA. I had a final round of interview with hiring managers at my dream company. We had a few good laughs and I seem to have most or all skills they are looking for for the position. They said they could see I will be productive from Day 1. We discussed the salary range and my earliest start date. Overall, I feel like it went pretty well. They have 1000+ employees and a large IT department. Let's call them Company A.

The Company A knew I had another offer from the beginning of the interview process, and they have tried to speed up the process for me. Today was the last date I could delay my answer for the offer with Company B. Company A knew about this, and told me they will try to make decision by today.

Unfortunately I did not hear from them by the end of the day. I really wanted to work with Company A, so I rescinded the offer from Company B. It was a hard choice. But whether this is the right choice or not is not the focus of this question.

I plan to send a follow-up email or call to the HR contact tomorrow morning. **Given the above context that they knew of this offer**, and every staff from Company A who I have spoke with seemed very personable and professional, I want to ask your advice whether I should mention I rescinded the other offer. My feeling is that they might like me more, or I could look desperate. Should I mention it? Would it hurt if I mention? If I should, please suggest exact wording I could use.

Thank you.

Comment: It could look as though you are trying to pressure them into making an offer. Do carry on applying for jobs and interviewing,

Comment: Please don't turn down an actual offer for a potential offer.  You need to compare apples to apples, not apples to a promise of one.  As far as evaluation goes, it is: Company A = no contract, Company B = contract.  Which side is better should be obvious.  It sounds cut-throat, but you need to look out for your own interest, and promises are a dime a dozen.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Definitely agreed. Thank you for your advice

Comment: @Nelson I appreciate your suggestion. I am luckily in a position to comfortable turn down offers I am not fully satisfied with. If otherwise I needed to take a job in a very short time, I would most likely have had to pick up the offer I had.

Comment: @kyle my advice is still about comparing apples to apples.  If you're in a position to pick and choose then strictly speaking you can do whatever you want.

Comment: You're using "rescinded" incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr: *Nothing* you can say now will help you. It will be either neutral or negative. You should have kept the other offer on hold. Don't provide extra information when you don't have to. Follow up is fine, but kept it simple, clean, and don't offer more information.

I would suggest that you keep that information to yourself. Even if they were to give you an offer, it's entirely within the realm of possibility that they will lower your offered salary knowing this. They may also take this as a sign that they "have you" and increase the time to present you with an offer.

This is on top of which, they still *haven't made a decision* about you. You don't know who else they've spoken with, or how many candidates who are at the same level, or what the person who is ultimately responsible for the decision will say. There are *plenty* of examples where people who have been "perfect" have been passed over. *Also*, an offer is the *start* of negotiations. What if you don't like the offer and want changes made? What if they aren't willing to make the changes?

Feel free to follow up on the interview saying that you enjoyed the final round and you look forward to receiving their offer letter soon, etc. *Nothing* you can say now will help you. It will be either neutral or negative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Malisbad. "Nothing you can say now will help you. It will be either neutral or negative." This. Very much agreed!